# What is the mysql 5.5 equivalent for the sys.dm_fts_index_keywords_by_document in sql 2008

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008, full-text-search

I'm making a web application that uses the data in the [sys.dm_fts_index_keywords_by_document](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280607.aspx). I'm interested how many times a given term occurs in each string that is indexed.

For example, I have a table with a column called comments, the table has various strings in the comments field. When I make that column full text searchable, the  dm_fts_index_keywords_by_document  is created and I can see the word per document data. Can i do the same thing in mySQL?